# Regexmatch for multiple words in Sheets

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, match

I'm trying to write a REGEXMATCH formula for Sheets that will analyze all of the text in a cell and then write a given keyword into another cell.

I've figured out how to do this for a single keyword: for example,

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(F3, "czech"),"CZ",IF(REGEXMATCH(F3, "african"),"AF",IF(REGEXMATCH(F3, "mykonos"),"MK")))
```

What I'm having trouble with though is writing one of these values *only if* two or more terms are matched in the reference cell.

If I were trying to match one of two words, I realize I could use | as in:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(F3, "czech|coin"),"CZC"
```

etc

But in this instance I only want to produce CZC if the previous cell contains BOTH czech AND coin.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this:

```
=IF((REGEXMATCH(F3, "czech"))*(REGEXMATCH(F3, "coin")), "CZC", )
```

multiplication stands for `AND`